# Test-Path Access denied Error - To check if Directory Exists on Shared Drive/Folder using powershell with credentials

Tags: powershell, access-denied, network-share

I am trying to check if folder exists on network location using Test-Path powershell script with different credential having access to the Network Server but I am getting access denied error. Below is my script which I am trying to execute on local from where I am trying to connect to Network server:

```
$username="username"
$pass =  "@Passw0rd" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force

$cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $username,$pass
$pathExists = Invoke-Command -ComputerName . -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock {
    Test-Path "\\serverName\Folder"
}
Write-Host $pathExists
```

I am getting below error:

---

Access is denied
+ CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (\serverName\Folder:String) [Test-Path], UnauthorizedAccessException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ItemExistsUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.TestPathCommand
+ PSComputerName        : localhost

---

Note: Admin access for the account is given which is used for accessing Network path and directory

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: Seems like classic double hop issue

Answer (score 1):

The issue most likely is because the credentials stored in `$cred` don't have Admin privileges on your localhost, hence cannot impersonate your invocation.

Here I'm trying something similar to what you're trying, the user stored in `$cred` is an Administrator on remote host but does not have any permissions on my laptop (I'm obfuscating for obvious reasons):

```
PS C:\> icm remoteServer -Credential $cred {test-path \\remoteServer\c$\users}
True

PS C:\> icm remoteServer -Credential $cred {test-path \\localhost\c$\users}
True

PS C:\> icm -computername . -Credential $cred {test-path \\localhost\c$\users}
[localhost] Connecting to remote server localhost failed with the following error message : Access is denied. For more 
information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (localhost:String) [], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AccessDenied,PSSessionStateBroken
```

Edit:

Here is another solution to your problem, `Start-Process` using the remote credentials and save the results to a file (again obfuscating the name of the remote server):

```
$argument="-c `"`$path='\\remoteServer\c$\users';'Attempting Test-Path '+`$path;'Result is: '+(Test-Path `$path)`""

$initHash=@{
    FilePath='powershell.exe'
    Credential=$cred
    ArgumentList=$argument
    RedirectStandardOutput="$HOME\Documents\testPath.txt"
    WindowStyle='Hidden'
}

Start-Process @initHash

PS C:\> gc "$HOME\Documents\testPath.txt"
Attempting Test-Path \\remoteServer\c$\users
Result is: True
```

Comment: Hi Santiago thanks for your reply I tried the solution you provided but its giving error:

[<Server IP>] Connecting to remote server <Server IP> failed with the following error message : WinRM cannot complete the operation. Verify that the 
specified computer name is valid, that the computer is accessible over the network, and that a firewall exception for the WinRM service is enabled .
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (<Server IP>:String) [], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WinRMOperationTimeout,PSSessionStateBroken

Comment: Probably because PowerShell Remoting is not enabled on the remote server. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/enable-psremoting?view=powershell-7.1 @ankushmantri

Comment: @ankushmantri check out my latest edit, this is another option you can try without `Invoke-Command`